# Refactor GroupBy query so it doesn't get evaluated by EF Core

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework-core

I noticed a warning in my logs telling me that my AsQueryable() queries were being evaluated due to containing a GroupBy() method.

I am using it in several places in my app so want to refactor it out for performance.

I have an offers table where each user can make multiple offer entries for a job.  I want a query that returns a list of just the most recent offer for each job for a user as an IQueryable.

This was my solution:

```
db.Offers
    .AsNoTracking()
    .Where(x => x.UserId == userId)
    .OrderByDescending(x => x.CreateDate)
    .GroupBy(x => x.JobDetailId)
    .Select(x => x.First())
    .AsQueryable();
```

It works fine but it seem EF Core cannot translate that to a query, it must execute the query which isn't ideal as I am actually doing further work to query later in execution and then paging it before executing it.

How can I get the same effect  where  I get just the newest offer per JobDetailId without the `GroupBy`?  I can't see how it can be done.

I am using Entity Framework Core 2.0.1

Comment: You might just wait a little bit for EF Core 2.1, where they finally claim to implement `GroupBy` translation.

Comment: See: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/what-is-new/ef-core-2.1#linq-groupby-translation

Comment: I think you are right.  No point doing extra work if next release fixes it.  Thanks

Comment: One possible way I can think of is to start the query from the "grouping" entity (table), so no `GroupBy` will be needed. e.g. `db.JobDetails.SelectMany(x => x.Offers.Where(...).OrderByDescending(...).Take(1))` Btw, even if `GroupBy` translation is implemented, `OrderBy` before `GroupBy` will not have effect (it should be after).

Comment: Ha!  That's a great idea.  Now I have to decide if I do the work or be lazy and wait for the update... hmmm...

Comment: It depends. [the second calendar quarter of 2018](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/what-is-new/roadmap) could be start of April (best) or end of June (worst).